# Having Moore's law is it worth looking for more algorithms?

Tags: algorithms

knowing that Moore's law states that **is the observation that the number of transistors in a dense integrated circuit (IC) doubles about every two years.** is it worth looking for more algorithms?

Comment: Please do not delete your question after receiving an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful not only to you but also to others in the future.  Deleting your question after receiving an answer can be considered impolite to answerers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1. Better algorithms, that run in less time complexity - work way better than just an increase in constant factor for large enough input, but more transistors is just a constant factor of work.
2. We have reached the "end" of this "law". Now we are in an era where its hard to make transistors smaller due to quantum effects on them.
3. Having newer and better algorithms will make programs run faster on **current** computers, and we wont have to always buy new ones.
4. Why not have both? more transistors + newer algorithms = even better performance!

Answer (score 0):

The quest for new algorithms is unending. It is not just about solving the solved problems faster, it is about how to solve more problems.

By the way, improvements by a factor $2$ is peanuts. In extreme cases, algorithmic improvements allow you to gain factors like $2^{3000}$, for instance.